# performing segue from appdelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, appdelegate

I have the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //make sure that the user credentials are still ok
    if (userLeftApplication){
        BaseViewController * baseViewController = [[BaseViewController alloc]init];
        BOOL detailsAreOK = [baseViewController credentialsValidated];
        if (!detailsAreOK){
            [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier: @"fromSplashToLogin" sender: self.window.rootViewController];
        }
        userLeftApplication = FALSE;
    }
}
```

However, I get the following exception when trying to perform the segue:

```
Attempt to present <LoginViewController: 0x2012e180> on <FirstViewController: 0x1f59cef0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

and the user is not being directed there.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rootViewController isn't currently defined. You can't 'perform a segue from the App Delegate', segues are transitions between view controllers. You need to launch the view controller rather than perform a segue.

```
self.window.rootViewController = baseViewController;
```